# Почему Android Studio не загружает json повторно?

Tags: java, json, android-studio

Я только начал изучение android studio и для первого проекта решил сделать приложение для получения курса валют.

Сделал его через получение json с https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js и расшифровку с помощью `volley`.

Все работает, но я заметил, что **если получить результаты, отключить интернет и нажать "получить" снова, то появляются опять те же результаты вместо ошибки.** Я скопировал json на свой сайт и поставил его url в приложение, и тут все работает нормально: с интернетом - результаты, без интернета - ошибка.

Мне кажется это как-то связано с кешем, но почему результаты c cbr кешируются, а с моего сайта нет?

Comment: Вы уверены, что Android Studio вообще имеет отношение к Вашей проблеме? Вы json получаете через код. Так покажите этот код. Причем здесь редактор-то?

Comment: Могу предположить, что JSON объект, в котором сохраняется результат, остается. Попробуйте после получения и отображения приравнивать свой объект к `null`, тогда будет выскакивать `NullPointerException`. Судя по всему, метод, который дает результаты, не получает этот JSON снова, те не обновляет его. Попробуйте каждый раз получать этот JSON заново, те переписать его. В случае неудачи будет `null`, и тогда можно будет выловить ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла установка кеширования в request:

**request.setShouldCache(false);
myQueue.add(request);**

Однако все равно не понятно почему cbr кешировался, а мой - нет.